# Inserir resumo quando houver alteração em um Array PHP

Tags: php, array, lógica

to com um dúvida que talvez possa ser fácil, mas to quebrado a cabeça, tenho uma tabela que é gerada através de um array, segue código abaixo:

```
    foreach($grupo_arr $k => $v){

  ?>  
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $num_array[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $maq_array[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $grupo_arr[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $producao_array[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo (($producao_array[$k]) * 2); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $segunda_array[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $terceira_array[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $producao_r_array[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo (($producao_r_array[$k])*2); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $eficiencia_array[$k]."%"; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } //fecha foreach
```

gera a tabela abaixo (foto):

[image: tabela]

como podem ver tem uma coluna "Grupo", esses grupos vão de 1 até 5, pois bem, gostaria que a cada alteração em um grupo, tivesse uma linha abaixo com o resumo desse grupo, como uma média dos valores de produção, eficiência etc, mas esse não é o problema, o problema é como incluir essa linha com o resumo a cada alteração de grupo, alguma ideia, agradeço desde já!

Contexto: o usuário filtra por data, o que eu quero fazer é que já venha separado na consulta, na hora que o user filtra, não precisa de refresh, a imagem do post reflete como está hoje, porém sem o resumo por grupo

resultado esparado seria esse da foto abaixo, feito em excel, linhas em amarelo

[image: tabela resultado]

Comment: Confesso que não entendi, você quer que isso ocorra automático, sem o usuário dar refresh na página?

Comment: @Marcelo obrigado pelo retorno, o usuário filtra por data, quero que já venha separado na consulta, na hora que o user filtra, não precisa de refresh, a imagem do post reflete como está hoje, porém sem o resumo por grupo

Comment: Pode criar um if antes do grupo para inserir os valores

Comment: Ahh... você quer fazer totais por grupo, rs

Comment: Você cria uma variável antes do inicio do loop com o valor do primeiro grupo, dentro do loop compara essa variavel com o grupo atual, se for diferente voce insere o total, depois do loop você insere o ultimo total, pois ele não será possivel dentro do loop, espero ter sido compreensivel.

Comment: @Marcelo entendi sim, na imagem tem somente 2 grupos, porém serão 5 grupos, você sugere compilar os 5 grupos em 5 variáveis antes do loop? Acrescentei uma imagem com o resultado esperado também.

Comment: Não, a variavel recebe o novo grupo assim que ele muda para ser comparado com o proximo novamente, vou colocar um exemplo na resposta

Answer (score 1):

Não conheço a estrutura de dados antes desse bloco que colocou então vou dar um exemplo de como seria totalizar por grupo usando uma query

```
...
$SuaQuery->Execute();
$Row = $SuaQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Inicio o Row

$subtotal = 0;

while($Row){ // Enquanto houver registro em Row
  $grupo = $Row["grupo"]; // Pega grupo
  do {
    // Aqui o seu html por linha
    echo("valor item: ". $Row["valoritem"]."<br>");   
    $subtotal += $Row["valoritem"];
    $Row = $SuaQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Avanca registro

  }while($grupo == $Row["grupo"]); // Enquanto for mesmo grupo

  if ($grupo != $Row["grupo"]){
    // Aqui coloca o html dos totais do grupo anterior
    echo($subtotal."<br>");
    $subtotal = 0; // Zera subtotal para o proximo grupo

  }
}
```

Fiz de cabeça pra passar a ideia, a ideia é você entra no loop com o primeiro grupo, vai inserindo linha até que o grupo não muda, quando mudar voce insere o total e pula pro proximo e assim sucessivamente, não importa o numero de grupos.

Esse esquema é o mesmo que extrato de banco quando agrupa por data e da os totais de cada dia

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que funcione.

```
foreach($grupo_arr $k => $v){
    $c1 += $producao_array[$k];
    $c2 += $segunda_array[$k];
    $c3 += $terceira_array[$k];
    $c4 += $producao_r_array[$k];
    $c5 += $eficiencia_array[$k];

    $ln ++ ;
   if($grupoant == grupo_arr[$k]){
   ?>

 <tr style="background:#ffff00">
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td><?php echo $c1; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $c1*2; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $c2; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $c3; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $c4; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $c4*2; ?></td>

    <td><?php echo $c5 / $ln; ?> </td>
  </tr>
   <?php

    $c1 =0;
    $c2 = 0;
    $c3 = 0;
    $c4 = 0;
    $c5 = 0;
    } else {

  ?>  
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $num_array[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $maq_array[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $grupo_arr[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $producao_array[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo (($producao_array[$k]) * 2); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $segunda_array[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $terceira_array[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $producao_r_array[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo (($producao_r_array[$k])*2); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $eficiencia_array[$k]."%"; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php
 }

$grupoant = $grupo_arr[$k];  
} //fecha foreach
```

Answer (score 0):

A minha sugestão é você criar um if antes do grupo para comparar os valores

Exemplo:

```
$qtde  = 0;
$grupo = 0;
$soma = 0;
foreach($grupo_arr $k => $v){

  ?>  
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $num_array[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $maq_array[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $grupo_arr[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $producao_array[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo (($producao_array[$k]) * 2); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $segunda_array[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $terceira_array[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $producao_r_array[$k]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo (($producao_r_array[$k])*2); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $eficiencia_array[$k]."%"; ?></td>       
  </tr>
 <?php
  if( $grupo > 0 ){
        if( grupo == $grupo_arr[$k] ){
          $qtde++;
          $soma =+ $producao_array[$k];
        }else{
          $media = soma / qtde;
          $qtde = 0;
          $soma = 0;
    ?>
        <tr> 
           <td>Total </td><td><?php echo $media; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php     

        }//fim do if interno
    } //fim so if
    $grupo = $grupo_arr[$k];
  <?php } //fim do for
```

Aí você acrescentar as outras opções